# How do I integrate omnipay Sage Pay Server driver with Sylius?

Tags: symfony, opayo, sylius

I am currently looking to create a Sage Pay Server integration for my Sylius store and I have installed ("omnipay/sagepay": "~2.0") the Omnipay SagePay driver.  There is currently a lack of documentation on the Sylius project regarding integrating other payment methods.

I am aware that the Payum bundle supports Omnipay Sage Pay and so Sylius should also, but there is some integration to be done.

My question is can someone outline the steps required for me to write the integration and any resources with similar implementations?

Thanks

Comment: I developed a Sagepay integration with Sylius https://github.com/sbarbat/SyliusSagepayPlugin

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in `"omnipay/sagepay": "~2.0"`. The `SyliusOmnipayBundle` is already shipped with Sylius Standard edition. It helps you integrate Omnipay payment gateways.

Look here the documentation: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusOmnipayBundle/index.html.

As you can see in the [list of implemented gateways](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusOmnipayBundle/installation.html#implemented-gateways): it works with Sage Pay Server.